# Common Javascript File for all Themes

Tags: theming, javascript

I have a multi-site installation using **[domain access module](http://drupal.org/project/domain)** and each sub-domain has its own theme. I have a javascript file which is common to all the themes. Right now I've placed the js file inside all the themes folder. Is there a way to place the js file in a common location so that all themes can share it ? Can I use **[Libraries API](http://drupal.org/project/libraries)** module for this purpose ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can use the [Libraries API](http://drupal.org/project/libraries) for this.  The docs explain all of this fairly well.   This is best for things that change infrequently.

For my custom Javascript libraries (which I work on continuously), I make module with an instance of [hook_library](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_library/7)

```
function mymodule_util_library ()
{
    $path = drupal_get_path("module", "mymodule_util");

    $libraries = array();

    $libraries["mymodule_util"] = array(
        "title" => "MyModule Javascript Utilities", 
        "version" => "0.0",
        "js" => array(
            $path . '/UTIL.js' => array(),
            $path . '/UTIL.HTML5.js' => array(),
            $path . '/UTIL.COLOR.js' => array(),
            $path . '/UTIL.MATH.js' => array(),
        ),

        'weight' => -10,
    );

    return $libraries;
}
```

Put the module in "site/all/modules" so all of your sites can see it, then enable it on the sites you need.

Then, wherever you need these JS libraries, you use [drupal_add_library](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_library/7)

```
drupal_add_library("mymodule_util", "mymodule_util", $every_page);
```

Typically, this is in a `hook_block_view` or a preprocess function.

Answer (score 0):

**[MPD's](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/users/835/mpd)** solution is very elegant. But since I'm new to Drupal and I don't know anything about module development (yet), I used a different method. The method I used to solve this problem was :

1. I placed the js file in the main theme.
2. I made the remaining themes as **sub-themes to the main theme**.

I know this is not a very elegant solution but this is an easy solution for newbies in Drupal.